# React.js: Element type is invalid:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a sample react.js project in VS 2019

My Index.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

// Create browser history to use in the Redux store
const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href');
const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: baseUrl });

// Get the application-wide store instance, prepopulating with state from the server where available.
const initialState = window.initialReduxState;
const store = configureStore(history, initialState);

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement);

registerServiceWorker();
```

My App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import NavBar from './components/NavBar'
import CoursesList from './components/CourseList'


export default class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavBar />
                <CoursesList />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

On running I am getting error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `NavBar`.

I am using Material UI

NavBar.js

```
import React from 'react'
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar'
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
const NavBar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
                        React & Material-UI Sample Application
                </Typography>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    )
}
export default NavBar;
```

PAckage.json

```
"name": "React_Material_UI",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
  "jquery": "3.3.1",
  "react": "^16.0.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
  "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
  "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.8",
  "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
  "reactstrap": "^6.3.0",
  "redux": "^3.7.2",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
  "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
},
"devDependencies": {
  "ajv": "^6.0.0",
  "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
  "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
  "eslint": "^4.1.1",
  "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
  "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.50.3",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
  "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1"
},
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "lint": "eslint ./src/"
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: You wrote `Navbar.js` in your question. Make sure your file is `NavBar.js` because thats whats being used in your code to import.

Comment: Yes, it is `NavBar.js. @NabeelMehmood

Comment: What version of material-ui/core are you using?

Comment: Version of Material Ui 4.4.0

Comment: I removed the extra classes to make sure your navbar config works in codesandbox. The navbar component seems to be rendering just fine. 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/hardcore-blackburn-vpl91

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, can you share your package.json content? Because your code seems fine.

Comment: @gavri pls check question. I have updated

Comment: But in your dependencies I see no reference to material-ui should be   "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "4.4.0",

Comment: Can you // with npm
npm install @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core

Comment: It would be great if you could give us a github link as none of the solutions mentioned above worked

Comment: Not sure also if material 4.4 will work with react 16.0, you should try upgrading react and react-dom too to 16.9

Comment: Please do make sure material ui is in your node_modules using `npm install @material-ui/core --save`

Comment: You seem like a beginner , So here are some tips.1) You can directly you Component instead of React.Component as you have already imported it . 2) Try to avoid using JQuery in React as much as possible as it compromises React's functionality. React has its own bootstrap known as Reactstrap or React-Bootstrap . As the normal Bootstrap 3,4 uses jquery , it is not recommended to use that aswell

Comment: @gavri.. You are correct, for some reason the vs 2019 was not adding the package to the project.

Comment: I added it and upgrade the react... now it is working

Comment: Cool glad it works ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try to import `NavBar` like this in `MyApp.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { NavBar } from './components/NavBar'
import CoursesList from './components/CourseList'


export default class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavBar />
                <CoursesList />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```